# header("Accept", "application/json;v=1") doesn't work in Gatling tests?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

For some reason

```
http("Update WishList")
.put("/api/update/${id}")
.header("Accept", "application/json;v=1")
.body(ELFileBody("bodies.json")).asJSON
.check(status.is(200))
```

causes `> status.find.is(202), but actually found 406`

But I know the service expects `"application/json;v=1"`

Checked the actual requests with Fiddler and found that the `Accept` header is `"application/json"` instead of `"application/json;v=1"`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Fiddler showed - ```Accept: application/json``` ... interesting.
Updating the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `asJSON` construct is to automatically force the `Accept` header of the request to `application/json`, hence, overriding your initial header.

Just remove `asJSON` and it should be alright.

Comment: I just looked at ```asJSON``` in ```RequestBuilder.scala``` and found that it only sets headers (and overrides in my case). So @notdryft you're right
       
```def asJSON: B = header(HeaderNames.Accept, RequestBuilder.JsonHeaderValueExpression).header(HeaderNames.ContentType, RequestBuilder.JsonHeaderValueExpression)```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

```
var httpConf = http.baseURL("http://example.com")
.header("Accept", "application/json;v=1")

var testSetup = setUp(testScenario.inject(virtualUsers).protocols(httpConf))
```

For me it sends the relevant header:

[image: Gatling Taurus Header]

Gatling version is [2.3.0](https://gatling.io/2017/08/31/gatling-2-3-0/)

---

The configuration was generated by [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-gatling-and-taurus) tool using the following YAML syntax:

```
execution:
- executor: gatling
iterations: 1
concurrency: 1
ramp-up: 1
hold-for: 1
scenario: some_scenario

scenarios:
some_scenario:
default-address: example.com
headers:
Accept: application/json;v=1
requests:
- url: /
      follow-redirect: false
```